# Scheduled emails to include only posts and calendar events for the upcoming week

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, automation

Please be kind, I'm new to WordPress and PHP. :)

I volunteer with a local animal rescue group (non-profit). We are migrating our web site to be WordPress. On our current site, we can go in and create new pages and then have those pages included in our weekly newsletter. This is all automated based upon the dates of the entries.

1. Is this possible with Wordpress either natively or through a plugin
2. If plugin, what terms do I need to search for because I'm not finding anything that will replicate our existing process.
3. What might be some pitfalls that I need to watch out for when reviewing the plugins (if this is the correct route to take)? For example, some plugins don't use the Wordpress taxonomies for the data, they create their own specialized tables. Is this a Pro or a Con?

We are using hosting at SiteGround if that helps.

Based on this article, https://barn2.co.uk/mailchimp-wordpress-blog-posts-by-email/, they seem to have outlined the steps that we need to take to pull in the blog posts but what about the calendar events - can we pull those in too? And the article doesn't mention being able to schedule this out.

Help.

Comment: Found this link mentioned in a youtube video: https://eventcalendarnewsletter.com and seems to be what I'm looking for. Still checking out other options but thought I'd include it here for anyone else in a similar dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with Mailpoet (https://www.mailpoet.com/). It does exactly what I needed it too.